Code Signing a Tauri application on Windows and MacOS
I've been developing an application over some time now that is based on Svelte and a .NET backend. The application is a webpage, that I also build as a Tauri application, so that the user is able to use it as a desktop application.
Personally, I am completely blank when it comes to signing applications, and I would appreciate a little help in regards to the process. The guides I find online seem to either be outdated, such as the official Tauri Code Signing documentation, use widely different methods, or they are using GitHub Actions, which I don't think I can use since the project is stored in Azure DevOps, and without a pipeline set up, I don't think I can use the secrets in there.
Currently, I do the work on my local application, push the code, merge it to another branch, publish it to an AKS cluster, update the pod, and the application is now running on the domain I use for testing. To build the Windows desktop application, I run "npm run tauri build" in the terminal to generate a .msi or .exe file, and do the same on Mac to generate a .dmg file. These files are then uploaded to a container in Azure Blob Storage. There is a button in my application that fetches these files through a URL directly to the file in the container, and the end user can then install the app.
Right now, the application is treated as a scary file by the OS, and I would therefor like to sign the application. I have ordered an EV Code Signing Certificate, and am looking to store it in Azure Key Vault. My distributor said I could use the same certificate for Code Signing on Mac as well, but is this true, as the Tauri documentation for Code Signing on MacOS explicitly describes that I need a certificate from the Apple Developmer Program?
And the bottom line of this post - how do I sign the application? Do I just need to set environment variables, build the app, and the Tauri builder signs it for me? Do I have to download a program to sign the file, or what is the best practice in my situation. The install file is packaged and uploaded to Blob Storage, and the web page gives a download link directly connected to that container and file.
Thank you in advance for any tips!

For anyone finding this post in the future, being unsure how to do it, just like I was, use Azure Sign Tool instead. Here is a link to a good guide from the certificate issuer I used:
https://trustzone.com/knowledge-base/how-to-sign-files-with-azure-sign-tool/

Tauri has an open pull request to add support for azuresigntool so it can run automatically during the standard npm run tauri build workflow. Either that feature or support for custom signing commands seem likely to be added in the future.

Code signing on Mac will work only with the Apple issued certificate because they require developers to complete the notarization process of the binaries using the Apple Developer account.
Once you have the Apple-issued certificates, you can use this instruction to code-sign your binaries on Mac.
For Windows platform it's a bit different and depends if you have software EV or hardware key.
But the basic step-by-step guide can be found here.

Very helpful with the info about the Apple specific certificate, and I kind of had that feeling. The documentation looks fairly straight forward as well, which is nice. The Tauri documentation you sent says it only applies to certificates from before June 1st 2023, but I could still follow that for the most part? I have a software EV stored in Azure Key Vaults

Haven't worked with AKV, but I can imagine you want to build a simple signing of the binaries (main bundle, and sidecars) so once you put it all together it's already signed, and you need to sign only the installer (or whatever you use there).
TL;DR: build it on your dev machine before you do full blown CI/CD pipeline.

@hagru The Tauri documentation for code signing shows the process for file-based certificates. EV certificates are required to be stored on an HSM that prevents export, and OV certificates added that requirement last year. In other words, the Windows code signing method described in their documentation will not work until they update the process. In the meanwhile, you need to build your app without a signature and follow your CA's recommended process for signing applications as a separate step.

Just to add to Jon's point, for Windows, we usually use Windows Store that allows to upload unsigned binaries, and then distributes signed ones with the internal Windows CA.
